# No suitable conversion user-defined conversion with std::bind()

Tags: c++, callback, std, stdbind

I'm trying to implement a Button class which invokes a callback when the button is clicked.

```
class Button
{
  public:
    void SetOnMouseClickCallback(std::function<void()> f);
  // Some other stuff
  private:
    std::function<void()> callback;
};
using ButtonPtr = std::unique_ptr< Button >;

void Button::SetOnMouseClickCallback(std::function<void()> f)
{
    callback = f;
}
```

In my App class I want to initialize all of my buttons and eventually assign a callback to them:

```
void App::Initialize()
{
    ButtonPtr b = std::make_unique<Button>(100.f, 100.f, 200.f, 50.f, "texture.jpg");
    b->SetOnMouseClickCallback(std::bind(&Foo)); // Error here under std::bind
}

void App::Foo()
{
    cout<<"bar";
}
```

I've been stuck here for the entire day and I have no clue anymore. Hope you can help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foo is not a `void()`. You forgot to bind it to the current instance:

```
std::bind(&App::Foo, this)
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! Also thanks  @NathanOliver for clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

A non-static member function has an implicit function parameter hat is the object to be called on.  Because of this you need to pass to `bind` the object to be called on.  That means you should use

```
b->SetOnMouseClickCallback(std::bind(&Foo, this));
```

If you want to use the current object or

```
App call_on;
b->SetOnMouseClickCallback(std::bind(&Foo, &call_on));
```

if you want it to have it's own object.